# django-celery celerybeat periodic task running every 5 seconds regardless of interval

Tags: redis, celery, django-celery

I've never experienced this issue before, despite a few projects using celerybeat and django-celery. I have used redis for the backend.

For some reason, periodic tasks are being run every 5 second, regardless of what the interval is set as. I know that the beat scheduler does in fact look at django-celery scheduler because when I disable the task, it stops running. However, regardless of whether I set it to run every 3 hours... or every 5 minutes... the task continues to run every 5 seconds.

Any ideas as to what's wrong?

Comment: Did you recently update to the new version of Celery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a new issue that the celery team is addressing.

https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/943#issuecomment-8146492